# How to autoload service namespace in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have created some library services in `app\Library`. I used `AppServiceProvider` to bind that service using following code:

```
$this->app->bind('App\Library\Globalfunction', function ($app) {
    return new Globalfunction();
});
```

**app\Library\Globalfunction.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Library;

    class Globalfunction {
        protected $_ci;
        public $siteConfig=array();
        public $smtpConfig=array();
        public $socialConfig=array();

        public $paramConfig;
        public $paramFrom;

        public function test($param) {
            return $param;
        }
    }
?>
```

To use this test() in controller i am including namespace using following:

```
use App\Library\Globalfunction;
```

once namespace is included i use following code:

```
$globalFunction = new Globalfunction();
echo $globalFunction->test('hello');
```

All of this code working fine but i don't want to add `use App\Library\Globalfunction;` in each file so is there anyway i can do that? is there any autoload file where i can put this and i can access `Globalfunction`?

I google solution for that and i tried several solutions like add this in composer or create package etc but it's not working so please if anyone have solution for this problem please let me know.

Comment: you have mentioned  trying composer way. after that approach  `composer dump-autoload` is needed.

Comment: @Kul yes i did that too but it's not working. if you sure i can do that with composer then i will provide composer code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can follow the same approach as Laravel?

Let me give you an example on how to achieve this.

First, create a `Helpers.php` file in `app/Helpers.php`. 
You also need to autoload it.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories",
        "database/providers"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Once that is done, you could define a function as such in your newly autoloaded `Helpers.php`:

```
if(! function_exists('global_function')) {

    function global_function()
    {
        return new \App\Library\Globalfunction();
    }
}
```

Then to use it anywhere, you can just do this.

```
global_function()->test('hello');
```

This is just a simple example. Obviously there are a lot of considerations you have to make before implementing this. 
However, Laravel has a similar approach to providing global helper functions. For example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session; 

// This
echo Session::get('key'); 

// is the same as 

echo session()->get('key');
```

Comment: Yes this is the one solution like `use App\Library\Globalfunction;` but i want use class object instead of function. I know this code will do same thing but my first priority is object. can i do that?

Comment: `global_function()` will return an object of `App\Library\Globalfunction`. So I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Yes you are right. I just want to know that is that possible to autoload service class without create or use helper file?

Comment: Not that i know of :)